# How to display a property in ng-repeat based on some other property of JSON data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I have this JSON file that I used `$http()` to get. It is something like this:

```
[ {
    "sno": "3",
  "eventname": "hockey",
  "event-type": "sports",
  "A-team": "mme",
  "B-team": "eee",
  "Gender": "male",
  "time": "2017-11-24 00:00:00",
  "isresult": "0",
  "result": "",
  "match-type": "semi",
  "venue": "downs"
}]
```

I need to display `item.result` as N/A if `item.isresult==0` and a string if `item.isresult==1`. How do I do that?

Comment: You can use `ng-if`. `<p ng-if='item.isresult === '1''`>{{item.result}}</p>

Comment: you can use  [filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter)

Comment: filter is not doing it

Comment: @SatyamRaj post your code.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/w55pehyg/

Comment: `<li ng-repeat='item in items | filter : {result: 1}'>{{item | json}}</li>`

Comment: I need to display `item.result` as N/A if `item.isresult==0` and a string if it is `1`

Comment: @SatyamRaj Update the question accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ng-if

```
<div ng-if="item[0].isresult ==='0'">
```

Answer (score 0):

Use ng-show

```
<div ng-show="item[0].isresult ==='0'">
```

Answer (score 0):

Say your list is named "items -

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items track by $index">
    <div ng-show="item.isresult === '0'"> N/A </div>
    <div ng-hide="!item.isresult === '0'"> {{stringToBeDisplayed}} </div>
</div>
```

I'm guessing your string is a variable you're storing. I'd also suggest you use boolean values for item.isresult instead of strings or numbers to avoid possible errors.